# killing queued commands before they start

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've queued a backgrounded command via

`command 1 && command 2 &`

`command 1` is currently running, however I need to make sure `command 2` is never executed.

If I need to kill `command 1` in order to ensure this, that is fine.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to kill `command1`, then that will work. Otherwise you may be able to just rename `command2` to something else - then when the shell tries to execute it, it won't find the command:

```
$ mv command2 command2.old
```

Comment: so killing the PID of `command 1` will cause `command 2` to never execute?

Comment: Yes, that's what the `&&` does. If you wanted it to continue even if `command1` doesn't complete successfully, you'd replace `&&` with `||`.

Comment: ah nice. the old logical operator. learn something every day!